# Can integration spoil real-analyticity?

Tags: real-analysis, examples, real-analytic-structures

Is there an example of a function $f:(a,b)\times(c,d)\to\mathbb{R}$, which is real analytic in its domain, integrable in the second variable, and such that the function 
$$ g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R},\qquad g(x) = \int_c^d f(x,y) dy$$
is not real-analytic on $(a,b)$?

**Edit:** What about an example of bounded $f$ satisfying the above?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y}\; dy = \dfrac{2}{3} \left((x^2+1)^{3/2} - |x|^3\right)$$
for $x \in (-1,1)$.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, if the integral is improper as in your other question. E.g.
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin x\,dy}{(y-\cos x)^2 + \sin^2x}
=\begin{cases}
\frac\pi2&x\in(0,\pi)\\
0& x=0,\pi,2\pi\\
-\frac\pi2&x\in(\pi,2\pi)\\
\end{cases}
$$
— an example due to Hermite ([1870](//zbmath.org/?q=an:02.0307.01)).

Comment: This is a very nice example. Could there exist a bounded $f$ with given property?

Comment: I am asking, because in my other question [(link here)](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215853/improper-integral-int-01-frac-expctx-sqrt-expbt-11-expatx-1) I am able to express the integral as a sum of two improper ones and one with bounded integrand.

Comment: @H.Berbeleque No, I don't think this can be done with a bounded integrand. See e.g. Theorem 12.12 in [Bartle](https://books.google.com/books?id=xuARCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA199).

Comment: (Just to be clear, the question I first answered had no boundedness hypothesis. You may want to do your edits in such a way that existing answers still make sense.)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I feel guilty for first accepting your answer, and consequently changing my mind. My sincere apologies for that. As for the edit: thank you very much for pointing this out. Indeed, I should have added a remark on boundedness instead of incorporating it into assumptions, so I do edit it the better way now.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this is too obvious to be interesting, but if we have bounds $\frac{1}{n!} \left| \frac{\partial^n}{(\partial x)^n} f(x,y) \right| < C_n$ on all of $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ such that $\sum C_n r^n$ converges for some $r>0$, then we get the conclusion.

This is because the Taylor series with respect to $x$ then converges on circles of radius $r$ around any point of $(a,b)$. Write $U$ for the open subset of points in $\mathbb{C}$ which are within distance $r$ of some point of $(a,b)$. These Taylor series give an extension of $f$ to $U \times (c,d)$, holomorphic in the first variable. (They agree on overlaps, since they agree on the real interval where they overlap.) Moreover, $|f| \leq \sum C_n r^n$ everywhere on $U \times (c,d)$.

We want to claim that $\int_c^d f(x,y) dy$ is holmorphic on $U$. By [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem), it is enough to check that $\int_{x \in \gamma} \int_{y=c}^d f(x,y) dy dx=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma \subset U$. By Fubini, we may switch the integral to $\int_{y=c}^d \int_{x \in \gamma} f(x,y) dx dy$, and the inner integral is zero since $f$ is holomorphic. (We may apply Fubini because we have a uniform bound for $f$ throughout $U \times (c,d)$.)